# Google Cloud SQL multiple instances w/ single server SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-sql

I'd like to use the same client certificate to connect to any of my Google Cloud SQL instances.  Is there a way to use the same server certificate for multiple cloud instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Cloud SQL currently does not support sharing a certificate across multiple instances.